# Триггеры в oracle BD

Tags: база-данных, oracle, триггер

Делаю триггеры для базы данных с таблицей "Товары"(айди,имя,айди группы, входная цена, розничная цена, количество) и "Группы товаров" (айди, имя, количество, сводная стоимость, наценка). Во время вставки в таблицу продуктов срабатывает ошибка:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, GROUP_ID,ENTRY_PRICE, COUNT)
VALUES ('Телевизор Philips',23, 10000, 5)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: триггер 'USER1.UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_BEFORE' недействителен и вызвал сбой при перепроверке достоверности
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

Код:

```
 CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."PRODUCT_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "GROUP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ENTRY_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
        "RETAIL_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
        "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_ID")
          REFERENCES "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" ("ID") ENABLE
       ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
      PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
     NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
    
      CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_BEFORE" 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
      v_group_id NUMBER;
      v_count NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      -- Получаем идентификатор группы товаров для текущего товара
      v_group_id := :NEW.group_id;
    
      -- Обновляем количество товаров в группе
      UPDATE product_group
      SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product WHERE group_id = v_group_id);
    
      -- Обновляем сводную стоимость группы
      UPDATE product_group
      SET c_retail = (
        SELECT SUM(entry_price * count)
        FROM product
        WHERE group_id = v_group_id
      );
    END;
    /
    ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_BEFORE" ENABLE;
    
      CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_AFTER" 
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
      v_group_id NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      -- Получаем идентификатор группы товаров для текущего товара
      v_group_id := :NEW.group_id;
    
      -- Обновляем количество товаров в группе
      UPDATE product_group pg
      SET pg.count = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM product p
        WHERE p.group_id = v_group_id
      )
      WHERE pg.id = v_group_id;
    
      -- Обновляем сводную стоимость группы
      UPDATE product_group pg
      SET pg.c_retail = (
        SELECT SUM(p.entry_price * p.count)
        FROM product p
        WHERE p.group_id = v_group_id
      )
      WHERE pg.id = v_group_id;
    END;
    
    /
    ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_AFTER" ENABLE;
    
      CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_C_RETAIL_TRIGGER" 
    AFTER UPDATE ON product FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      -- Пересчитываем сводную стоимость для соответствующей группы
      UPDATE product_group pg
      SET c_retail = (
        SELECT (p.retail_price * p.count)
        FROM product p
        WHERE p.group_id = pg.id
      )
      WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
    END;
    /
    ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_C_RETAIL_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
    
      CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
        v_markup product_group.markup%TYPE;
        -- Получаем наценку на группу товара
      BEGIN
        SELECT markup
        INTO v_markup
        FROM product_group
        WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
    
        -- Вычисляем розничную цену
        :NEW.retail_price := :NEW.entry_price * (1 + v_markup);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          -- Eсли группа товара не найдена
          :NEW.retail_price := 0;
      END;
    END;
    /
    ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" ENABLE;
    
    
      CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."GROUP_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0, 
        "C_RETAIL" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
        "MARKUP" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_CHK1" CHECK (markup >= 0 AND markup <= 1
    ) ENABLE
       ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
      PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
     NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
    
      CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" 
    AFTER UPDATE OF MARKUP ON product_group
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      -- Обновляем розничные цены в таблице "Товары" для соответствующей группы
      UPDATE product
      SET retail_price = entry_price * (1 + :NEW.markup)
      WHERE group_id = :NEW.id;
    
    END;
    /
    ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" ENABLE;
```